# Real-time Questions and page-refresh

Tags: feature-request, live-refresh, new-questions

This is a feature request, following the resolution of [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156434/real-time-questions-vs-page-refresh/156436#comment450787_156436). I wonder if the following would be feasible:

I understand that there is a 5(?) minute cache on new questions. This means that if a new question is posted, I get a notification through the socket connection that there is a new question. If instead of clicking on that notification, I refresh the page, the notification is lost and the new question doesn't load.

Now, I get the argument for having a 5-minute cache delay (server load, etc), but would it be possible to have a separate cache (or some such) for those questions that are posted in those 5 minutes, so that they can be pushed as notifications to someone who hit refresh (or newly landed on the site)?

Comment: It's only 1 minute cache, I don't think that we need another cache for that.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Got a link for that? I'm pretty sure it's 5 (or something longer than a minute, at any rate).

Comment: We considered invalidating those caches based on notifications, but there are a few things to figure out still before we're at a point where we know if we can do it.

Comment: @Anna nothing official, but [in this recent question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147488/new-questions-page-caches-for-too-long) and its comments it says the cache should be between half minute to minute and half and the dev who answered didn't say otherwise. (I assume that if it was 5 minutes he would comment on that)